# VBScript how to set the connection string

Tags: sql-server-2005, vbscript, connection-string, database-connection, wsh

I am not sure whether it has been disscussed before or not but I have the following code (I changed from example for an Access database.)

I don't know what to put inside the ***'Provider'*** and the ***'Data Source'***. I'm using **MS SQL Server 2005** and how to find this information in my machine? Please, even I try to follow from here  *http://www.connectionstrings.com/*, yet I still don't know how to do it.

```
Dim conn, sql
sql = "SELECT * FROM tblOutbox"
Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
With conn
      .Provider = "myProvider"
      .Mode = adModeReadWrite
   .ConnectionString = "Data Source=mysource;" & _
          "database=myDbase.mdf;   "
      .Open 
End With
If conn.State = adStateOpen Then
      WScript.Echo "Connection was established."
End If
conn.Close
Set conn = Nothing
```

here is using access database:

```
Dim conn 
Dim sql
sql = "SELECT * FROM tblOutbox"
Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
   With conn
      .Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
      .Mode = adModeReadWrite
      .ConnectionString = "Data Source= f:/Status.mdb"
      .Open 
   End With
   WScript.Echo "Connection was opened." 
conn.Close
Set conn = Nothing
WScript.Echo "Connection was closed."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution thanks to your help. 
Under the Administrative Tools, Data Source (ODBS), driver tabs, I use provider: SQLNCLI, my Server: Data Source, and I add Recordset rs to the code. It seems that, without this one, the connection is not established. I don't know what happened.

```
Dim conn , rs, sql, ConnString
sql = "SELECT * FROM tblOutbox"
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
With conn
      .Provider = "SQLNCLI"
      .Mode = adModeReadWrite
      .ConnectionString = "SERVER=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=F:\Test2.mdf;Database=Test2.mdf; Trusted_Connection=Yes;"
      .Open
      WScript.Echo "Connection was established."
End With
rs.Open sql,conn
If conn.State = adStateOpen Then
      WScript.Echo "Connection was established."
Else
  WScript.Echo "No Connection ."
End If
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
conn.Close
Set conn = Nothing
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the provider in the connection string

```
conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Data Source=XXX;Initial Catalog=XXX;User ID=<XXX>;Password=<XXX>;"
```

Note: I haven't tested it but it should work

Comment: To use the SQL 2005 client, use a provider of SQLNCLI

Comment: SQLOLEDB and SQLNCLI both work with SQL 2005. I've not seen a performance difference with either.

Comment: Ok, from my code, i remove provider, and mode replace with this code :    conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Data Source=F:\admin.mdf;Initial Catalog=admin;" I also remove uid and pass coz i'm not using it. This type of error appeared: Error: Invalid authorization specification
Source: Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server
System: These workstations have sessions with open files on this server:

Answer (score 1):

For all your connection string needs: http://www.connectionstrings.com/

Answer (score 0):

With SQL Server you don't connect directly to the file. Access, being a file-based RDBMS is a little different.

Following your example, it would look something like this:

```
Dim conn, sql
sql = "SELECT * FROM tblOutbox"
Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
With conn
      .Mode = adModeReadWrite
      .ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;server=[servername];database=[databasename]uid=[insertuser];pwd=[insertpassword];"
      .Open 
End With
If conn.State = adStateOpen Then
      WScript.Echo "Connection was established."
End If
conn.Close
Set conn = Nothing
```

There's usually a more compact way of doing this, but without the context its hard to give a better example

Comment: What is servername? where can i find it? Answer from Kane stated have Data Source, Initial catalog and etc. What are differences with yours? This one using c# : Connection String ("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=F:\Test2.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True"). Any useful things that i can take from here?

Comment: The server name is the instance of SQL Server you are trying to connect to. The database name is the name of the database - not the .mdf file.

Comment: If you don't know what they are, ask the admin.